# How do I get time data from my Bing Search History?

Tags: bing

Microsoft [claims](http://onlinehelp.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/ff808483.aspx) that Bing search history can provide time data. But when I log in with my WindowsLiveID and view my search history, all I see is dates. Is there some hidden way to get the search time out of the history data?